# ElasticSearch match + parent ID query + snippets

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got a parent-child relationship of documents (parent) and pages (child). I would like to write a query that gets all pages from a certain document that match a search string, as well as retrieving snippets. My code so far (using the php library):

```
[
    'size' => 100,
    'from' => 0,
    //this sets the snippets with highlight
    'highlight' => [
        'fields' => [
            'content' => (object)[]
        ]
    ],
    'query' => [
        'bool' => [
            'must' => [
                'match' => [
                    'content' => $_GET['search']
                ],

                //only get pages in this doc
                /*'parent_id' => [
                  'type' => 'page',
                  'id' => $hit['_id']
                ]*/

                'has_parent' => [
                    'type' => 'document',
                    'ids' => [
                        'values' => [$hit['_id']]
                    ]
                ]

            ],
            /*'filter' => [
                'term' => [
                    '_parent' => $hit['_id']
                ]
            ]*/
        ]
    ],


];
```

As you can see I've tried the filter, has_parent and parent_id clauses, but nothing seems to work, either returning empty sets or errors. Does anyone have any pointers on how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles upon this, I found the answer. You have to use a filter query:

```
[
    'size' => 100,
    'from' => 0,
    //this sets the snippets with highlight
    'highlight' => [
        'fields' => [
            'content' => (object)[]
        ]
    ],
    'query' => [
        'filtered' => [
            'query' => [
                'match' => [
                    'content' => $_GET['search']
                ],
            ],
            //only get pages in this doc
            'filter' => [
                'ids' => [
                    'type' => 'document',
                    'values' => [$hit['_id']]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],


];
```